# Prove that function is rational

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f(z)$ is holomorphic in unit circle $D$ and continious in $\overline{D}$. Let $|f(z)|=1$ on unit circle. Prove that $f(z)$ is rational.

Maximum module theorem must be useful... Also we can say that $\exists z_0\in D: f(z_0)=0$. Question is how to use that $f\in C(D)$. I'm seriously stuck...

Comment: You probably heard about the Schwarz reflection principle. You can apply it to $i \log f(z)$

Comment: I'd suggest inducting on the number of zeros in unit disc $D$.  As base case, when multiplicity is $1$ then $f$ is an analytic homeomorphism of $D$ to $D$ so you know exactly its form.  The fact that rational functions are closed under composition allows you to complete the inductive step.